# PHP Triangle of Images

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a triangle using 2 sets of images. It is relatively easy to do using *. Its roughly 40 lines of code and its abit ridiculous approaching it this way. I have tried looking online but haven't found a solution

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Dinosaur.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';           
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {
            echo '<img src="Penguin.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';                            
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Dinosaur.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';           
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Penguin.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';            
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Dinosaur.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';           
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Penguin.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';            
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Dinosaur.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';           
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Penguin.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';            
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Dinosaur.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';           
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Penguin.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';            
        }
        echo '<br>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="Dinosaur.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';           
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? https://repl.it/EijH/5

Replace:

```
* with `<img src="Dinosaur.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>`and
^ with `<img src="Penguin.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>`
```

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$rows = 15;

for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j <= $i; ++$j) {
        if($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo ($j % 2 == 0 ? "<img src='http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/images/prism-base-square.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px';/>" : "<img src='http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/images/pyramid-base-square.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px';/>");
        } else {
            echo ($j % 2 == 0 ? "<img src='http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/images/pyramid-base-square.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px';/>" : "<img src='http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/images/prism-base-square.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px';/>");
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

for($i = $rows; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    for($j=$i; $j > 1; --$j) {
      echo ($j % 2 == 0 ? "<img src='http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/images/prism-base-square.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px';/>" : "<img src='http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/images/pyramid-base-square.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px';/>");
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added a PHP HTML one too~